# motivation for character of group in group theory

Tags: group-theory, characters, motivation

I am reading Milne's book, Group theory. And there is a section named 'the linear characters of a commutative group', but I don't see any result that help us understanding group theory itself.
Does it help with the classification of finite simple group? Is it involved in any classification theorem of certain type of groups?

A quick google search seems to imply that it is only useful in other branches of mathematics.

By the way, the definition is, a linear character (or just character) of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $G\to \mu(\mathbb{C})$ where $\mu(\mathbb{C}):=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ |\ |z|=1\}$ with multiplication as group operation.

If it really comes from other branches of mathematics, it is welcome to talk about the origin of character group, just like the name 'solvable group' comes from the Galois groups of finite field extensions that can be obtained by radical extension.

Comment: It is a way to classify properties of groups. You could use it to show two groups are not isomorphic, for instance. But representation theory is quite popular and apparently powerful mathematics (I don't know anything beyond Artin's chapter on characters)

Comment: As a topic in group theory, it's a warmup to both Pontryagin duality and to representation theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qiaochu mentioned, characters of an abelian group generalize to [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) for possibly nonabelian groups, a deep and beautiful subject.

If you want applications inside group theory, representation theory provides a proof that [every group of order $p^a q^b$ is solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_theorem). While proofs avoiding representation theory have been found, it's my understanding that they're much more complicated.

Indeed, there's a proof on the wikipedia page, and you can see how essential it is to understand the characters of $G$. (Moreover, characters in the sense of this wikipedia page specialize to characters in the sense of your question when $G$ is abelian).

These characters (of possibly nonabelian groups again) are also essential for the proof that [all groups of odd order are solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem). You can see the wikipedia page on [character theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory) for more.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Lovely answer, though the idea of 'solvable group' is not quite useful in developing group theory because it is studied only because they are Galois groups of finite field extensions that can be obtained by radical extension. So the part about solvable group doesn't count as motivation inside group theory to me.

Comment: @ZWu -- that's not true at all, and (respectfully) you should probably learn more group theory before making such sweeping claims about why people study things. Solvable groups are studied (in part) because they are precisely the groups you get by gluing together finitely many abelian groups. In this way, we can bootstrap our way to nontrivial theorems about solvable groups by using induction on the derived length and facts about abelian groups! Through this lens, the Feit-Thompson theorem tells us that every group of odd order is finitely many abelian groups in a trenchcoat.

Comment: As one instance of this being useful for pure group theoretic information, a motivating question in the history of group theory has been understanding to what extent the converse to [lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) is true. For general groups, the best we can do is the [sylow theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems), but for solvable groups we can do better! This is [hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup#Hall's_theorem). In fact the groups with all hall subgroups are exactly the solvable ones!

Comment: Thanks, good to know!

Comment: See also here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/groupdet.pdf and the references there to the papers of T.Y. Lam (they can be found on the Internet).